# Using EntityFramework for search is MASSIVELY slow. How can I improve the speed of the query?

Tags: sql-server, performance, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I'm using Entity Framework 5.0.0 in an MVC 4 web site.

Part of the site allows the user to search for records in the database.  The search may contain up to 10 search criteria that may touch (generate a where clause) 4-5 tables and returns data from 14 tables.

The search page offers many fields by which to search:  Keywords, Title, Date, etc etc.

The search feature allows both an "OR" or an "AND" combination of search terms.
For example, one can require that Title AND Date match, or that Title OR Date match.

The query looks something similar to this:

```
Dim searchQuery As IQueryable(Of MainTableClass) = Nothing
Dim query As IQueryable(Of MainTableClass) = Nothing
Dim queries As List(Of IQueryable(Of MainTableClass)) = New List(Of IQueryable(Of MainTableClass))

Using database As DataContext = new DataContext
    searchQuery = ( From x In database.MainTableClasses. _
                            Include("Secondary.Third.Fourth"). _
                            Include("Secondary.Fifth.Sixth"). _
                            Include("Eighth"). _
                            Include("Nine.Ten.Eleven.Twelve"). _
                            Include("Thirteen.Fourteen")
                Select x)
    '   Some things here to limit the initial set that searchQuery returns
    '   eg:  searchQuery = searchQuery.Where(Function(m) m...blah blah)

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Title) Then
        query = (From x In database.MainTableClasses Where x.Secondary.Title = model.Title Select x)
        queries.Add(query)
    End If

    If Not Nothing Is model.Date Then
        query = (   From x In database
                    Where x.Nine.Any(Function(a) model.Date < a.Value)  )
        queries.Add(query)
    End If


    '
    '   Now to combine the results
    '
    For Each item As IQueryable(Of MainTableClass) In queries
        Select Case model.SearchType
            Case SearchType.OR      '   Or the search terms
                searchQuery = searchQuery.Union(item)

            Case Else               '   And the search terms
                searchQuery = searchQuery.Intersect(item)

        End Select
    Next

    '
    '   Run the query
    '
    results = searchQuery.ToList
End Using
```

The issue is that Linq is turning the actual query into 5700 lines of SQL and it takes over 9 seconds to run on Azures largest SQL database offering.  Totally unacceptable.  I could write the main search query in SQL by hand in under 30 lines.

So, what can I do to refactor this query to make it run more quickly?  Is EF/Linq not the right tool?  Am I doing something totally wrong here?

Comment: That's not the right tool for the job. You better create a full text index on some field that will contain the concatenated data you need to search on, then use the solution described in http://www.entityframework.info/Home/FullTextSearch. Otherwise, you'll have to opt for Lucene / ElasticSearch and the likes.

Comment: That's a totally unacceptable solution.  If I were to write the SQL by hand it would work very quickly.  The data in these table is in constant flux - creating and maintaining a field that concatenated search data together is out of the question.

Comment: Could you explain the difference between the query generated by hand and by Linq ? In my opinion, you can avoid the many `Include` statements and maybe reload the references later. It can be a start..

Comment: The primary difference is the LINQ query is nearly 5700 lines long, and the hand-written query is ~10 lines.  I'll write up my solution in a little while.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution I came up with was to write the SQL by hand, and let Linq-To-SQL perform the ORM function to populate my data model:

```
Dim sql As String = "SELECT ... FROM Classes WHERE ..."
Dim model As SearchResultsModel = Nothing

model = database.Classes.SqlQuery(sql).ToList
```